# Shouldn't a full join get both sides even if one side has a null of both tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

This is not the full query(it is a subquery in a larger query). However, I know this is the part that is causing me a problem as I have taken it own and sourced it to it. I am trying to get both sides of two tables that don't always have matching composite keys. In particular, the GKey is not always the same.

I am currently using a full join, but I still get gaps on both sides. There is an example of how the data should essentially come out. You can see that there are nulls on both sides of the two different tables.

```
   Input
| A    | B    |
| 2    | NULL |
| NULL |  5   |
| 3    |  3   |
|Null  |  6   |

  Outcome 
| A    | B    |
| 3    |  3   |




 SELECT DISTINCT BudgetUnit / (WorkDaysInMonth * 8) AS B
        ,Unit / (WorkDaysInMonth * 8) AS A

    FROM BFact AS BMF
    FULL JOIN GFact AS GF ON 
    BMF.GLKey = GF.GKey
        AND 

        BMF.DKey = GF.DKey
        AND GF.AKey = BMF.BKey
        AND GF.PKey = BMF.PKey
    INNER JOIN DimDate AS DA ON GF.AKey = DA.DateKey
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are selecting FROM BFact, and then using GFact in an INNER JOIN after the FULL JOIN, you are turning your FULL JOIN into an INNER JOIN because no results that don't satisfy the last INNER JOIN will be returned.

You could make that last INNER JOIN into a LEFT OUTER JOIN to get the desired results.